# Cannot initialize EGL display: "Bad alloc (0x3003)" on running a sample app on arm platform

Tags: qt, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to run a very simple app using openGLES on the arm platform and I got this problem:

```
QEgl::display(): Cannot initialize EGL display: "Bad alloc (0x3003)" 
QEglContext::chooseConfig(): Could not find a suitable EGL configuration 
Requested: "type=es2 rgba=0,0,0,0 surface-type=window" 
Available: 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

I am using QT-4.8.0

Comment: Request something more realistic, like 8,8,8,8 ?

Comment: Maybe he means `rgba=0,0,0,0`

Comment: ah ok. but what it should be an how can i set it?

Comment: What windows system are you using? X11? QWS?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with my ARM embedded linux platform.
Check that your SGX drivers are install properly.
Check with hello_gles2 that it works properly.
OpenGL ES need the framebuffer in specific mode.
I used Qt 4.8.3 natively installed from sources.
Once ererything is properly installed, it is nice
to use Qt with openGL ES